# How to filter a list using an array of keywords?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want to filter a list so it only shows items containing **BOTH** keywords inside the array.
Ex.:

```
searchArray = ['sys', 'config']
```

If the user type 'sys config', should only show "System configuration" and hide other items.

So far I came up with this, but it's not working properly, cause it shows items that contains one of the words and not both.

```
var searchArray = search.split(" ");

for(x in searchArray){
    filteredMenu = $('.texto:contains(\'' + searchArray[x] + '\')')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `.every` one of the keywords is included:

```
const texts = [...$('.texto')]
  .filter(element => searchArray.every(
    substr => element.textContent.includes(substr)
  ));
```

Demo:

```js
searchArray = ['sys', 'config']

const texts = [...$('.texto')]
  .filter(element => searchArray.every(
    substr => element.textContent.includes(substr)
  ));
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="texto">
foo
</div>
<div class="texto">
config
</div>
<div class="texto">
sys config
</div>
<div class="texto">
system configuration
</div>
<div class="texto">
sys
</div>
<div class="texto">
bar
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! I'm getting undefined from .textContent tho, any suggestions?

Comment: `.textContent` should not ever return `undefined` when called on a DOM node. See edit for a live demo. If that doesn't work, can you edit your HTML into the question so we have a [MCVE] to debug?

Answer (score 1):

Also, in some cases it is useful to construct a **regular expression** ("regex") string, and to use this to perform the search.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution posted by a guy in Brazillian SO. Adding multiple `:contains` seems to work perfectly. Also, the answer from [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) works great!

```
var arrayBusca = ["config", "empresa"];
var stringBusca = '';

arrayBusca.forEach((item) => stringBusca = stringBusca.concat(`:contains("${item}")`));

console.log(stringBusca); // output: :contains("config"):contains("empresa")
```